# Should [eclipse-plugin-dev] be a synonym of [eclipse-plugin]?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

[eclipse-plugin-dev](/questions/tagged/eclipse-plugin-dev) has 63 questions.

[eclipse-plugin](/questions/tagged/eclipse-plugin) has 1761 questions.

Comment: I was about to suggest the same synonym, and additionally there is a huge overlap with [tag:eclipse-pde] and partially with [tag:eclipse-rcp].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, I don't think they should be synonyms.  Eclipse plugin development is a different enough activity from just *using* plugins for development that I think a separate tag is justified.  I strongly suspect that you'll find a lot of plugin development questions in [eclipse-plugin](/questions/tagged/eclipse-plugin) though.

Comment: Is it worth looking through the _eclipse-plugin_ tag and retagging any questions that talk about developing a new plugin to _eclipse-plugin-dev_?

Comment: @staticbeast: Yes, [this search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[eclipse-plugin]+development) shows that there a lot of them, so it's probably worth going through to retag them.  Particularly the ones that aren't answered, to give them a bump.

Comment: Isn't it equally worth writing up a better wiki then? I came here suggesting the same synonym, and it wasn't clear to me _at all_ that was the difference implied between the two of them. Neither did I see them being used in such a way. Isn't that already partly proof that it's _not_ a different enough activity from just using plugins?

Comment: @StevenJeuris Yeah, feel free to improve the tag wikis to make the difference more clear.  How people use (and abuse) tags really doesn't change the fact that using Eclipse plugins is a *completely* different activity than developing them.

Comment: That indeed doesn't change that fact, but it does [warrant questioning whether or not differentiating between the two tags is useful at all](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157711/157047).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think [eclipse-plugin-dev](/questions/tagged/eclipse-plugin-dev) should be made a synonym of [eclipse-plugin](/questions/tagged/eclipse-plugin).

At the time of writing:

[eclipse-plugin-dev](/questions/tagged/eclipse-plugin-dev) has 162 questions, and has 34 followers.

[eclipse-plugin](/questions/tagged/eclipse-plugin) has 4196 questions, and has 490 followers.

Selecting the 10 most recent [eclipse-plugin](/questions/tagged/eclipse-plugin) questions:

- [Pydev PyUnit issue when using thread.join to ensure all threads are joined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13724653/pydev-pyunit-issue-when-using-thread-join-to-ensure-all-threads-are-joined) (not directly related to plugins, more specific [pydev](/questions/tagged/pydev) applied)
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/13699830/590790 (about development, no [eclipse-plugin-dev](/questions/tagged/eclipse-plugin-dev) applied)
- [check if save button is clicked in eclipse plugin development](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13704868/590790) (about development, no [eclipse-plugin-dev](/questions/tagged/eclipse-plugin-dev) applied)
- [Plugins working in Eclipse Indigo, not in galileo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13698280/590790) (about development, no [eclipse-plugin-dev](/questions/tagged/eclipse-plugin-dev) applied)
- [Metrics Plugin issue in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13698192/590790) (plugin usage, tag would be **valid**)
- [can't run ScalaIDE in a XP without networks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13697953/590790) (not directly related to plugins, more specific [scala-ide](/questions/tagged/scala-ide) applied)
- [How do you sort elements underneath a project during Eclipse Plugin Development?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13689865/590790) (about development, no [eclipse-plugin-dev](/questions/tagged/eclipse-plugin-dev) applied)
- [Adding a Menu Item for only one Perspective](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13680177/590790) (about development, no [eclipse-plugin-dev](/questions/tagged/eclipse-plugin-dev) applied)
- [Job-buffer for IDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13674263/590790) (about development, no [eclipse-plugin-dev](/questions/tagged/eclipse-plugin-dev) applied)
- [RCP for creating standalone application, later converted to plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13677940/590790) (about development, no [eclipse-plugin-dev](/questions/tagged/eclipse-plugin-dev) applied)

**Out of 10 question, only 1 was talking about plugin usage** and didn't have another more relevant tag applied, 2 others were about plugin usage, but had related more specific tags applied. **7 were misusing the tag** [eclipse-plugin](/questions/tagged/eclipse-plugin).

This raises the following questions:

1. When would it be useful to differentiate between plugin development and plugin usage? Common plugin questions might be better of being tagged with an appropriate tag for that particular plugin.
2. As it stands now, the tag is in no way useful. The [difference Bill the Lizard specified](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98601/157047) is clearly not reflected in the tag usage. Is it even worth/possible cleaning this up?
3. What would be the *downside* of merging the two tags?

I believe it would be a lot clearer to make [eclipse-plugin-dev](/questions/tagged/eclipse-plugin-dev) a synonym of [eclipse-plugin](/questions/tagged/eclipse-plugin), merging them, and updating the wiki to reflect this tag is about usage and development. Probably people who are knowledgeable about the development of plugins are also capable of answering generic problems with plugin usage anyway.